# Parse deviceToken not in format

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I don't know why `deviceToken` in Parse isn't like GCM token which I get from my device.

In my device, i got GCM token like `APA91....` but when it stored to Parse my `deviceToken` become absurd format like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONLfa.png

What's going on with Parse? There is any wrong configuration?

Comment: Hi, did you find out what is going on? I got this issue too.

Comment: @tehmaestro correct your way to get token.cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `deviceToken` in parse, just use following code:

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            String deviceToken = (String) ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");
        }
    });
```

I was able to get the correct type with it of version 1.7.1. I don't know the newest version.

[image]